# Peer-to-peer network using C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, p2p

I am new to socket programming and need some help regarding establishing a new peer-to-peer network. What I have now is say a Server A connected to clients B and C respectively simultaneously. I am using the select() API to establish this, and so far this is working(A can communicate with B and C independently.) What I now want is to make B and C communicate with each other directly; say B requests to connect to C without involving A. B and C would both still be connected to A, but they will have a peer-to-peer connection amongst themselves to be able to talk to each other. Any idea how this works? I have tried making my client program acts like a server too with calls to listen() and accept(); but it simply freezes my client.

I have a user interface to throw commands at the client/server, if you are wondering how am I implementing this.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You can `select()` on your listening sockets, too, and not call `accept()` until you have a connection ready to be accepted to avoid it blocking.

Comment: Snippets of your code would probably be useful.

Comment: Google 'peer to peer protocols'.

Comment: Also, thread off the server instances.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to google it up; no help yet. Also, due to security reasons, I'm unable to share my code here too. Sorry about that, but I guess I'm asking you guys to unlock the door by finding a key, but which door I'm not mentioning :(

Comment: Any final conclusion @Saptarshi??

Answer (score 1):

For TCP connections, one peer has to be passively listening and the other has to be actively connecting. (There is one exception, TCP simultaneous open, which is probably not what you want.) In your example, to establish a connection between B and C, you can do it the same way as in A and B. I.e. you can make B listen&accept, and C connect.

Why your client freezes? Printing error message and `strace` are your friends.

Comment: I'm not sure as to why that happens. When I'm connecting A and B, everything works. But the moment I try to connect C to B with B still connected to A, it freezes. After I supply the connect from C, B neither accepts the connection nor does it perform any otherr operations(say displaying its own IP through a command, which previously worked). My guess is that B now actively listens for other connections and the existing connections via sockets are hibernating, but that's not my requirement and I tried to design my code so too. Let me try with strace. error messages are not printing here too :(